# BOSH - how resource intensive is it?

Tags: mobile

I'm writing a simple XMPP chat application. The interface has been made minimal to accommodate mobile devices. The client uses [strophe.js](http://strophe.im/) which utilizes a bi-directional persistent connection (BOSH) between the javascript application and XMPP server.

Would this persistent connection consume a lot of bandwidth? I know most mobile phone users have some sort of monthly data quota - I don't want to hog it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you do the math, you need to account for:

1. HTTP headers sent & received
2. Possible cookies to/from the server
3. BOSH typically sends a packet every minute both ways (called the empty body). This takes up considerable bandwidth.

You might want to consider using websockets instead.

http://blog.superfeedr.com/xmpp-over-websockets/

[Is there an open source WebSockets (JavaScript) XMPP library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1850162/is-there-an-open-source-websockets-javascript-xmpp-library)

The XEP (draft): https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-moffitt-xmpp-over-websocket-00