# how to create node xmpp sever that communicate with android chat applicaion

Tags: android, node.js, node-xmpp

i want to create android and iphone chat app, and i want to use XMPP using Nodejs. so i don't know about how node-xmpp-server will communicate with android app.

can node-xmpp-server can communicate with android app? if yes than, how can i create simple node-xmpp-server and simple android app that both can communicate.

i want use nodejs, xmpp and android if you have any other solution please let me know.

i have idea about socket.io but i dont want to use that.

please guide me,
thank you in advance.

Comment: i am also trying the same thing, but i am trying to implement it using socket.io.

Comment: i can do with socket, but socket may handle 10,000 socket connection. but i think XMPP has its own advantages over socket. how can i do same thing with XMPP?

Answer (score 0):

If you are opting node.js at ur server then I would suggest you to use Socket.io which is a better fit for chat apps onnode.io.
it provides client support libraries for android aswell.
have a look at  [this](https://www.quora.com/Which-is-faster-in-terms-of-sending-messages-by-a-chat-application-implementing-sockets-or-XMPP-CCS) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10360364/realtime-server-push-with-socket-io-or-strophe-js-xmpp-and-django).

Comment: yes i know that socket.io can do what i need, but i want to do same thing using XMPP, how it is possible using XMPP?.

Comment: As you mentioned in your question "if you have any other solution please let me know", so i thought of suggesting socket.io.
XMPP i have not explored much yet, so cant suggest on it.

Comment: i also said that in my question "i have idea about socket.io but i dont want to use that." i dont want to use socket.

Comment: sorry for missing that part.
any specific reason for not using socket.io??

Comment: as per my info, socket.io may limits 10,000 sockets. after that we have to perform load balancing. xmpp is more secure than socket. my company want to use XMPP.

Answer (score 0):

i recomended you to using xmpp, why, xmpp is minim resource fro mobile apps, i have created some apps using socket.io lib, but it need more than xmpp resource, for example in socket.io my apps need 100mb of ram, using xmpp, my app need 50mb of ram