# Is there open source chat library using websockets

Tags: javascript, websocket

I plan to create a chat on the site for users, and was wondering if there is already open source javascript library that I can use.

Comment: You may find the second answer on [Is there an open source WebSockets (JavaScript) XMPP library?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2037853) to be a helpful starting point.

Comment: They are only, libraries for push without websockets. And XMPP is only protocol ("file" format), but thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to have a look at **node.js / jquery**. Here's a [tutorial](http://martinsikora.com/nodejs-and-websocket-simple-chat-tutorial) on a chat (which supports web socket).

If you are using **Dojo Toolkit** there's something called [Cometd](http://cometd.org/) to implement a chat room too.

Or you could use [this](https://blueimp.net/ajax/) (but no websocket).

Comment: The task seems to trivial for the library.