# What's the current support for websockets XMPP client in web browsers?

Tags: browser, websocket, xmpp, strophe

What's the current (spring 2013) support of WebSockets technology in XMPP clients implemented in web browsers? I have read it's possible to turn on WebSockets module on the server (for example via [this module](http://blog.superfeedr.com/xmpp-over-websockets/)) but how can I connect to them from the browser? Are there any existing clients or extensions? I am particularly interested in [Strophe.js](http://strophe.im/) since it provides good work so far - using BOSH.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1850162/is-there-an-open-source-websockets-javascript-xmpp-library

Comment: Despite that question is not very 'current', it helped me a bit. Thanks! If you want some reputation, extend it as an answer and I'll accept since nobody else responded.

Comment: That won't be necessary. I'm glad that I could help out a bit.